# Error 86db089e when selecting an existing shape

Tags: vba, visio

I have the following code in my Visio VBA.
It works OK most of the time, but when the shape (pShape) is the FIRST selected shape on a page, I get the following error, which cannot be trapped

-2032465762  86db089e

```
Set wpage = wOwner.ContainingPage   ' Visio page with both owner and subordinate
GetSubordinates pShape, wlinks, "", 0   
' gets all subordinates of pShape into wlinks
ActiveWindow.DeselectAll  ' just in case
On Error GoTo 0
ActiveWindow.Select pShape, visSelect
On Error GoTo errtrap
ActiveWindow.Selection.Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Just after I posted, I saw the error. I need to make the selected page the current active page: 
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page = Application.ActiveDocument.Pages.Item(wpage.Name)